# Can motion tracking and Video Stabilization constrain to y axis only?

Tags: video, tracking

Is there a way to remove or ignore the tracking data of x or y axis? I just want to stabilize the up/down motion in a video because I'm doing a panning shot (rolling on wheels). As you can see, the red track seems to move the film to the left (outside) which is unwanted. Thanks.

[image: x-axis motion track]

Comment: somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12243/2d-stabilization-of-camera-pan

Comment: Indeed. Only reason I made this post was on the slight chance that the update since that post.

Answer (score 4):

In the compositor the Movie Input nodes has x and y offset values, once you add a tracker to the 2D stabiliser these become active. Just use the correction you need and plug it into the node distort>transform.
In your case just use the y value.
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

I use little different setup - shown in the picture - eliminates x axis movement by inverting it and adding it as transformation
(scale node is not used intentionaly)

[image: my setup]

Comment: Kinda of outdated due to Blender Blender3 but the idea is right. Thanks.