# Accessing Scale data from motion tracked point

Tags: tracking

I have a motion tracking point set to track location and scale. This works great, however, I can not figure out how to access the scale data in order to use it as part of a driver. Could somebody tell me where I can find the scale value for individual tracking points?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24038/can-motion-tracking-and-video-stabilization-constrain-to-y-axis-only

Comment: @cegaton I have an object tracked to the point, however, I also need to scale the object so that it maintains scale with the car in the video. The tracking point perfectly scales with an emblem on the car so I think I can use it to get the proper transition.

Comment: You can do corner pinning using tracking points. see: https://vimeo.com/71727578  and http://cgterminal.com/2011/06/25/blender-four-corner-pin-tracking-tutorial/

Comment: @cegaton Unfortunately corner pinning won't work in this situation, but I just did it by hand so don't worry about it. Thanks for trying to help.