# How to make tracker on footage A pan footage B's XY position?

Tags: camera, compositing-nodes, parent

If I track the same point on two footages, or just one, can I either: 1. use that tracker to parent to an X-Y transform node of a video or image in the compositor? or 2. make the same tracker on two different videos follow on top of each other? I'm trying to mimic footage A's active camera motion to a relatively static footage B without using a 3d camera if possible, obviously if footage B were a single image on a plane I know it would be easy to use a 3d camera how this guy does it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf6fQSI-WVk) but I'm not sure if it would even be possible do do that with footage, so if it can be done at all or inside the node editor even, that would be great to know!

tl;dr I want to make tracker on footage A be responsible for panning+position of footage B.

Comment: Use a **track postition node** that uses the information of  video A and connect the X and Y outputs to a the X and Y inputs of a **translate node** to control  the position of video B.  Read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip/38557#38557. As an alternative you can use a **stabilize 2D** node on the video B, but that uses the tracking information from Video A.

Comment: @Blenderandlenders please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62776/how-to-log-back-into-an-unregistered-account for infomation on how to merge your accounts.

Comment: Read also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24038/can-motion-tracking-and-video-stabilization-constrain-to-y-axis-only